# My code in R is showing wrong values in my barplot, how can I fix it?

Tags: r, dataset, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a barplot using a dataset on Public transport data in France (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/gatandubuc/public-transport-traffic-data-in-france)

The values shown in the y axis of the barplot are not the same as the ones in the dataset. Here's my code:

```
Trains <- read_csv("Trains.csv") 

Trains2 <- Trains %>% 
  group_by(`Departure station`) %>% 
  mutate(`Departure station`, 
         Departure =  `Departure station`, 
         `Number of late trains at departure`, 
         Retard_total = sum(`Number of late trains at departure`, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  distinct()

plot1 <- Trains2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Departure, y = Retard_total, fill = Retard_total)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=8),
         axis.title=element_text(size=8),
         plot.title = element_text(size=10)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "pink", high = "red") +
  labs(x = "Gare de départ", y = "Nombre de trains en retard", title = "Gares les plus touchées par les retards au départ")
plot1

top10 <- plot1 + scale_x_discrete(limits=c("PARIS MONTPARNASSE","PARIS LYON", "LYON PART DIEU", "PARIS EST", "MARSEILLE ST CHARLES", "PARIS NORD", "LILLE", "BORDEAUX ST JEAN", "RENNES","STRASBOURG"))
top10
```

Here's a picture of my barplot:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwXoq.png)

How can I fix this issue?

Thank you very much in advance

I tried selecting the two columns I needed for the x and y axis in the barplot to avoid any confusions but it's still giving me the same result. My code worked once but then I refreshed Rstudio and it starting showing me this issue.

Comment: In future, please run `dput()`, e.g. `dput(Trains2)` and paste the result into your question. The link you added requires a log in. Your plot is showing the correct value on the y-axis, but it is being converted to scientific notation. If you run `options(scipen = 999)`, that globally forces R to visualise numbers "normally". Does that correct your issue? I suspect it will given that the issue arose after starting a new RStudio session. You have to run  `options(scipen = 999)` each time you start a new session, or add it to your `.Rprofile` file so it becomes the default when you start R.

Comment: @LeroyTyrone Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it didn't correct the issue since the value on the y axis isn't the same as the one in the dataset. For instance,  the highest value shown in the barplot is equivalent to 80000000, whereas in the dataset the highest one is  67548.

Comment: Ok, run `dput(Trains2)` and copy the result into your question. That will make your issue reproducible. Thanks.